# Needed some diagrams and information about C# compiler

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, diagram

i'm looking for some information about c# compiler like syntax diagrams , lexical analyzer , how it finds tokens , syntax analyzer and ... .

unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this ,

any helps would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Roslyn is open-source, does this provide you the required information? http://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft .NET Compiler Platform, knows as *Roslyn* was open sourced couple weeks ago.

Go to http://roslyn.codeplex.com and get source code for both C# and VB.NET compilers. You can browser the source online at http://source.rosly.codeplex.com as well.

When you have the code, you can generate diagrams, find out how it finds tokens, etc.

Comment: is this the only one that used to compile the c# code or ... ?